# Firebase creating nested object on POST

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, micronaut

I am trying to HTTP POST a Treasure to a Firebase Real Time Database(2) using Micronaut's RxHTTP (1).

```kotlin
data class Treasure
(
    val treasureId : String? = null,

    val name : String,

    val description: String,

    val amount : Double,

    val lat : Double,

    val lng : Double
)
```

```kotlin
@Client("\${treauser.trasures.url}")
interface TreasureRepository : CreateTreasurePort
{
    @Post("/Treasure.json")
    override fun add(treasure : Treasure)
}
```

It posts but for some reason it nesting the object under uuid.

[image]

I do not want treasure to be there, I just want all five properties under the UID.

1: docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/httpClient.html#clientAnnotation
2: firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-post

Comment: None of the code you shared seems to write anything to Firebase yet, or at least not in a way that I'm familiar with. Can you explain (or include a link to the docs) of how this writes to the database, and how that translated to a support API/SDK, or a package/library that we can look at to see how it is supposed to work?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen@Client("\${treauser.trasures.url}") pulls in URL from application.yaml in Micronaut, and I am using the declartive http request api from Micronaut thttps://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/httpClient.html#clientAnnotation.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen by HTTP Post https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-post

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You might want to put that info into your question by clicking the edit link under it. I don't know Micronaut myself, but hopefully somebody with experience on that wil be able to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how could this be caused by just CURL sending the data with -X POST and I will update the question

Comment: It can't. Firebase will add the `-M...` type key when you `POST`, but it has no way to add the `treasure` level, as it doesn't have any knowledge about that. So that part my be present in the JSON that is being postted to the REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the @Body<sup>1</sup> annotation.

```kotlin
@Client("\${treauser.trasures.url}")
interface TreasureRepository : CreateTreasurePort
{
    @Post("/Treasure.json")
    override fun add(@Body treasure : Treasure)
}
```

1: Body Annotation: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/annotation/Body.html